# ld: warning: ignoring file liblua.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format (0x21 0x3C

Tags: lua, linker, static-libraries

macOS 12.4 / XCode 13.4.1

Trying to build lua 5.4.4 from source:

```
$ make
Guessing Darwin
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make all SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE" SYSLIBS="-lreadline"
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lapi.o lapi.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE   -c lcode.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lctype.o lctype.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o ldebug.o ldebug.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o ldo.o ldo.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o ldump.o ldump.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lfunc.o lfunc.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lgc.o lgc.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE   -c llex.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lmem.o lmem.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lobject.o lobject.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lopcodes.o lopcodes.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE   -c lparser.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lstate.o lstate.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lstring.o lstring.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o ltable.o ltable.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o ltm.o ltm.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lundump.o lundump.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lvm.o lvm.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lzio.o lzio.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lauxlib.o lauxlib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lbaselib.o lbaselib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lcorolib.o lcorolib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o ldblib.o ldblib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o liolib.o liolib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lmathlib.o lmathlib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o loadlib.o loadlib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o loslib.o loslib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lstrlib.o lstrlib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o ltablib.o ltablib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lutf8lib.o lutf8lib.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o linit.o linit.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o lua.o lua.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_3 -DLUA_USE_MACOSX -DLUA_USE_READLINE    -c -o luac.o luac.c
ar rcu liblua.a lapi.o lcode.o lctype.o ldebug.o ldo.o ldump.o lfunc.o lgc.o llex.o lmem.o lobject.o lopcodes.o lparser.o lstate.o lstring.o ltable.o ltm.o lundump.o lvm.o lzio.o lauxlib.o lbaselib.o lcorolib.o ldblib.o liolib.o lmathlib.o loadlib.o loslib.o lstrlib.o ltablib.o lutf8lib.o linit.o
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
ranlib liblua.a
gcc -std=gnu99 -o lua   lua.o liblua.a -lm -lreadline
gcc -std=gnu99 -o luac   luac.o liblua.a -lm -lreadline
ld: warning: ignoring file liblua.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A 0x2F 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 )
ld: warning: ignoring file liblua.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A 0x2F 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 )
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_luaG_getfuncline", referenced from:
      _PrintFunction in luac.o
  "_luaL_loadfilex", referenced from:
      _pmain in luac.o
  "_luaL_newstate", referenced from:
      _main in luac.o
  "_luaM_free_", referenced from:
      _pmain in luac.o
  "_luaU_dump", referenced from:
      _pmain in luac.o
  "_lua_checkstack", referenced from:
      _pmain in luac.o
  "_lua_close", referenced from:
      _main in luac.o
  "_lua_load", referenced from:
      _pmain in luac.o
  "_lua_pcallk", referenced from:
      _main in luac.o
  "_lua_pushcclosure", referenced from:
      _main in luac.o
  "_lua_pushinteger", referenced from:
      _main in luac.o
  "_lua_pushlightuserdata", referenced from:
      _main in luac.o
  "_lua_tointegerx", referenced from:
      _pmain in luac.o
  "_lua_tolstring", referenced from:
      _main in luac.o
      _pmain in luac.o
  "_lua_touserdata", referenced from:
      _pmain in luac.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_luaL_callmeta", referenced from:
      _msghandler in lua.o
  "_luaL_checkstack", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
      _doREPL in lua.o
  "_luaL_checkversion_", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_luaL_error", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
      _lstop in lua.o
  "_luaL_len", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_luaL_loadbufferx", referenced from:
      _doREPL in lua.o
      _dostring in lua.o
  "_luaL_loadfilex", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_luaL_newstate", referenced from:
      _main in lua.o
  "_luaL_openlibs", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_luaL_tolstring", referenced from:
      _pushline in lua.o
  "_luaL_traceback", referenced from:
      _msghandler in lua.o
  "_lua_close", referenced from:
      _main in lua.o
  "_lua_concat", referenced from:
      _doREPL in lua.o
  "_lua_createtable", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_lua_gc", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_lua_getglobal", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
      _doREPL in lua.o
      _pushline in lua.o
  "_lua_gettop", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
      _doREPL in lua.o
      _dostring in lua.o
  "_lua_pcallk", referenced from:
      _main in lua.o
      _pmain in lua.o
      _doREPL in lua.o
      _dostring in lua.o
  "_lua_pushboolean", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_lua_pushcclosure", referenced from:
      _main in lua.o
      _pmain in lua.o
      _doREPL in lua.o
      _dostring in lua.o
  "_lua_pushfstring", referenced from:
      _doREPL in lua.o
      _msghandler in lua.o
      _pushline in lua.o
  "_lua_pushinteger", referenced from:
      _main in lua.o
  "_lua_pushlightuserdata", referenced from:
      _main in lua.o
  "_lua_pushlstring", referenced from:
      _pushline in lua.o
  "_lua_pushstring", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
      _doREPL in lua.o
  "_lua_rawgeti", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_lua_rawseti", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_lua_rotate", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
      _doREPL in lua.o
      _dostring in lua.o
      _pushline in lua.o
  "_lua_setfield", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_lua_setglobal", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_lua_sethook", referenced from:
      _laction in lua.o
      _lstop in lua.o
  "_lua_settop", referenced from:
      _main in lua.o
      _pmain in lua.o
      _doREPL in lua.o
      _dostring in lua.o
      _pushline in lua.o
  "_lua_toboolean", referenced from:
      _main in lua.o
  "_lua_tointegerx", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_lua_tolstring", referenced from:
      _main in lua.o
      _pmain in lua.o
      _doREPL in lua.o
      _dostring in lua.o
      _msghandler in lua.o
  "_lua_touserdata", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
  "_lua_type", referenced from:
      _msghandler in lua.o
  "_lua_typename", referenced from:
      _msghandler in lua.o
  "_lua_warning", referenced from:
      _pmain in lua.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [luac] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [lua] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Darwin] Error 2
make[1]: *** [guess] Error 2
make: *** [guess] Error 2
```

is my toolchain broken?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I had binutils installed, so the build system was using binutils' `ar` to create the static library:

```
$ which ar
/usr/local/bin/ar
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/ar
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  admin  32 Jul 13 21:52 /usr/local/bin/ar -> ../Cellar/binutils/2.38_1/bin/ar
```

After uninstalling binutils:

```
$ which ar
/usr/bin/ar
```

I was able to compile lua